# Resetting develop and staging branches after a release

Tags: git, github, git-merge, rebase, pull-request

I'll give some context before jumping to the actual questions: I'm the only developer working on a project, where I have `main`, `develop` and `staging` branches, besides all feature/* and hotfix/* that I could potentially have during development.

The integrations between branches were made via pull requests using GitHub, some of them were made with merge commits, others with squash commits, so the result is that the branches got very messy. For example, I just merged staging to `main`, then updated (merged) `main` to both `develop` and `staging`. As I'm the only developer, I know that the content at this point for all the three branches is the same, but commit-wise is not: both `develop` and `staging` are 382 commits ahead of `main`.

When I create a pull request to `staging` over a branch checked out from `develop`, the pull request shows only the commits about the feature itself, which is good. But when I create the pull request to `main` over `staging`, a lot of commits that aren't related of this request are showing (because they are commits from `develop` and `staging`, but not in `main`) and making the code review messy, also the changelog management.

For me (and correct me if I'm wrong, please) the perfect scenario would be having `main`, development and `staging` with exactly the same content and commit count (i.e., development and `staging` show 0|0 ahead/behind `main`). I could delete and recreate both `develop` and `staging` branches from `main`, but (and here comes the first question) **is there a way to reset `develop` and `staging` branches without recreating them?**

The second question is kinda obvious: **which way do you think is the cleanest to handle the following pull requests to keep a clean situation in the future?**. I think that any merge-based solution will include at least one commit, so maybe the answer goes through rebase.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it messed up is because you did not create *real* merges. When you squash-merge, the *original* branch is not really merged into the target branch so it you try to merge again later, those same changes that had been merged (in a squash) will show up
(because they were not *really* merged, right?)..... *so*, when you want to merge between those 3 branches, **do real merges**.

Rule of thumb there goes something like: **do not merge-squash branches that are long-lived**. squash is fine when you want to merge a feature-branch, for example, because you won't be starting stuff *from* the original feature branch. It reaches EOL, say. But long-lived branches *do* need to keep commits that are merged *in order* when you merge them.

Then.... if you want to have those 2 branches with the same as main (contents **and** history), just move the branch pointers (remember: in git, branches are just pointers to commits... they can be moved around):

```
git checkout main
git pull # get the latest from remote main
git push -f origin main:develop main:staging
```

Now all 3 (remote) branches point to the same commit. The local branches, you would need to move them as well:

```
git branch -f staging main
git branch -f develop main
```

And now everything is in sync.

Comment: Thank you very much! the rule of thumb makes complete sense in this scenario. To test the solution you provided me I have to ask for advanced permissions or disable protection hooks (as we work with pull requests I'm not able to force push towards the repo) but it looks like it would work